# Drawing a roaming figure in a field, with less flickering

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, console, animation

I'm a student to programming. I currently just working a thing where the player can walk around a field of hashtags. so far you can only walk horizontally but before i go any further, i realized that the program flickers a lot? Is there any cure for this? I'm using python 3 on windows.

```
import os
from msvcrt import getch

def clear():
    os.system( 'cls' )

map1=("#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#")
def draw_setting(x):
    edit_map=list(map1)
    del edit_map[x]
    edit_map.insert(x,"o") #The player is represented by o
    print (*edit_map, sep='')

x=0
draw_setting(x)
while True:
    key = ord(getch()) #Fetching the key pressed
    if key==100: #If d is pressed
        if x<30:
            x=x+1
            load_map=1
    elif key==97: #If a is pressed
        if x>0:
            x=x-1
            load_map=1
    elif key=="stop":
        break
    if load_map==1: #Only render if necessary
        clear()
        draw_setting(x)
        load_map=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) library.

```
def clear():
    os.system('cls')
```

You complain about "flicker", which is related to perceptible "slowness". Almost certainly your environment supports xterm/vt100 ANSI escape sequences. You forked off a command, `cls`, that printed `<ESC>[H` to put cursor at top of screen, and `<ESC>[2J` to clear screen. You could more quickly `print()` such escape sequences.

```
map1=("#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#")
```

Please don't do that. Express it as `map1 = '#' * 31`

```
del edit_map[x]
edit_map.insert(x, "o")
```

Delete and insert both have linear cost, which is small for a 31-char string, but still, avoid turning O(1) ops into O(n) ops. Instead, just assign: `edit_map[x] = 'o'`.

You can reposition the cursor with a simple CR rather than ANSI sequences: `print(edit_map + '\r')`. That alone could make the flicker negligible.